# D3 adds extra lines between points

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linegraph

I have a D3 line and point chart, which is working, except that it adds extra lines between unrelated points:
[image]

Code is in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8gzv7rrh/1/ the data doesn't work, though, as it comes through a websocket which is not included in the fiddle.

```
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#visualisation").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var valueline = d3.line()
.x(function(d) {
  return x(d.time);
})
.y(function(d) {
  return y(d.value);
});

var xaxis = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(x));

var yaxis = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(d3.axisLeft(y));

function graphData(data) {
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.time;
  }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  }));  

  var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data);

  circles.exit().remove();

  circles.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2)
    .merge(circles)
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d.time);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d.value);
        });

  var line_graph = svg.selectAll(".line")
    .data([data])

  line_graph.exit().remove();

  line_graph.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .merge(line_graph)
        .attr("d", valueLine);

  svg.select(".x").call(d3.axisBottom(x));
  svg.select(".y").call(d3.axisLeft(y));

}
```

I have no idea why it is adding these extra lines

Comment: Without seeing an example of your data, looks like you need to sort your data before drawing - the lines connect the data points in the order they appear in the data array, if the data order doesn't follow a chronological order, lines like this will appear.

Comment: @AndrewReid Right you are, that was stupid of me. I'll delete this question

Comment: @Alex No reason to delete, can be instructional for someone else

Comment: @BlackICE Ok, I'll leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure dataset is ordered. D3 will link datapoints in the order they appear in the dataset, not necessarily in the order that the x component of the datapoint would suggest